# How to access POST data sent from a browser to Rikulo Steam Server

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, stream, dart, rikulo

I ask the browser to POST JSON data to the stream v0.5.5 server using ajax. In the server side, how can I receive the data from the ajax request?

My client:(Google Chrome)

```
void ajaxSendJSON() {
  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); // create a new XHR

  // add an event handler that is called when the request finishes
  request.onReadyStateChange.listen((_) {
    if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
      (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)) {
      // data saved OK.
      print(request.responseText); // output the response from the server
    }
  });

  // POST the data to the server
  var url = "/news";
  request.open("POST", url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  request.send(mapTOJSON()); // perform the async POST
}

String mapTOJSON() {
  print('mapping json...');
  var obj = new Map();
  obj['title'] = usrTitle.value == null ? "none" : usrTitle.value;
  obj['description'] = usrDesc.value == null ? "none" : usrDesc.value;
  obj['photo'] = usrPhoto.value == "none";
  obj['time'] = usrTime==null ? "none" : usrTime.value; 
  obj['ip']= '191.23.3.1';
  //obj["ip"] = usrTime==null? "none":usrTime; 
  print('sending json to server...');
  return Json.stringify(obj); // convert map to String i.e. JSON
  //return obj;
}
```

My server:

```
void serverInfo(HttpConnect connect) {
  var request = connect.request;
  var response = connect.response;
  if(request.uri.path == '/news' && request.method == 'POST') {
    response.addString('welcome from the server!');
    response.addString('Content Length: ');
    response.addString(request.contentLength.toString());
  } else {
    response.addString('Not found');
    response.statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
  }
  connect.close();
}
```

Again, I don't want the browser to ask for data from the server!
What am I doing is to asking the browser to submit the JSON data via ajax, and I just don't know how the server (Rikulo Stream v0.5.5) gets the "content" of data? All code is written in Google Dart Language M3. No Javascript!

Answer (score 1):

POST is not supported well in Dart SDK, but Dart team planned to enhance it. Please stargaze it [here: issue 2488](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=2488).

On the other hand, since what you handle is JSON, you can listen to HttpRequest (I'm assuming the latest SDK) and convert List to String and then to JSON. [Rikulo Commons](http://api.rikulo.org/commons/latest/rikulo_io/IOUtil.html) provides a utility to simplify the job as follows:

```
import "package:rikulo_commons/io.dart";

IOUtil.readAsJson(request, onError: connect.error).then((jsonValue) {
   //handle it here
});
```